# How do you loop a gls() function such that you regress each column of a data frame on a set of independent variables

Tags: r, loops

Essentially, I have a data frame consisting of columns: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

I want to regress

```
gls(a~h)
gls(b~h)
.
.
.
gls(g~h)
```

and save these regressions to a list that contains the coefficients and residuals for each regression. And I plan to extract them using:

```
sapply(list, coef,) 
sapply(list, residuals,)
```

However my data set has thousands of columns in it. How can I do this in r using a loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do you really want to use a loop or do you want to use a package that is made for doing regressions with all possible subsets of columns? Also, do you want it to be all possible subsets or just drop 1 column at a time in order?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using a list and a loop (I have used dummy data). Also the function `gls` requires formulas so you can use smartly `as.formula()` with the respective names. Here the code:

```
library(nlme)
#Data
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10,1,2),
                 b=rnorm(10,1,5),
                 c=rnorm(10,1,10),
                 d=rnorm(10,1,1),
                 e=rnorm(10,1,8),
                 f=rnorm(10,2,2),
                 g=rnorm(10,1,9),
                 h=rpois(10,0.8))
#Code
index <- which(names(df)!='h')
#List
List <- list()
#Loop 
for(i in index)
{
  #name covariates
  v1 <- names(df[,i,drop=F])
  v2 <- 'h'
  v3 <- as.formula(paste0(v1,'~',v2))
  List[[i]] <- gls(v3,data=df)
  names(List)[i] <- v1
}
List
```

Output:

```
List
$a
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -19.74037

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
  1.7981345   0.4395727 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 2.252625 

$b
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -22.96146

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
   1.562261   -3.610542 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 3.36939 

$c
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -27.98972

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
  -2.839797    3.759619 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 6.31713 

$d
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -12.75595

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
  1.0048859   0.7997716 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 0.9408642 

$e
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -30.02588

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
-0.08323116 -0.11157127 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 8.148097 

$f
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -19.21926

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
  2.7446886  -0.1064889 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 2.110568 

$g
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: v3 
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -29.19166

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           h 
   8.483339   -4.746078 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 8 residual
Residual standard error: 7.341237
```

Comment: Quick question. When I apply this to my data frame I get the following error: Error in model.frame.default(model, dataMod) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'mktrfbeta'). Here my mktrfbeta is acting as my h. It has the same number of observations as every other column in the data frame however.

Comment: @CairnHearties Maybe check is there is any `NA` or something like that or also the length for other variables!

Comment: I got it to work! One more quick question. Say I wanted to regress on more than one variable, how would I work on the index?

Comment: @CairnHearties In that case you can create a new value inside the loop like `v_n` and include it in the formula carefully. You can play around the formula and see outputs. I hope that helps!

Comment: How would I construct the index. Does r have an and function that would allow me to say something like !='x','y'.

Comment: @CairnHearties Check the `%in%` operator and you can combine it with `names(df)`!

Answer (score 0):

Using `reformulate`.

```
rg <- names(d)[!names(d) %in% "h"]
setNames(lapply(rg, function(x) 
  lm(reformulate(x, "h"), d)[c("coefficients", "residuals")]), rg)
# $a
# $a$coefficients
# (Intercept)           a 
# -0.1397861   1.5754488 
# 
# $a$residuals
# 1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
# 0.39570210 -1.23447278  1.18733412  1.54241624 -1.48755817  2.11774373 -1.67997168 
# 8           9          10          11          12          13          14 
# 0.73094508  0.86101269  1.73417911  0.51527327 -1.82142311  4.82370202  0.77177476 
# 15          16          17          18          19          20 
# -0.84239625 -1.94642481 -0.16537106 -0.08808104 -4.66894171 -0.74544252 
# 
# 
# $b
# $b$coefficients
# (Intercept)           b 
# 0.5718898   1.5104357 
# 
# $b$residuals
# 1            2            3            4            5            6 
# 2.307058939 -0.145249746  1.307418592 -0.006905091 -4.424897936  1.889070097 
# 7            8            9           10           11           12 
# 0.378266810  2.533283303  2.634312498  1.890371544  1.171424560  0.004782197 
# 13           14           15           16           17           18 
# 0.360489930  0.540625651 -2.526815303  0.937237885 -0.139997905 -3.699625069 
# 19           20 
# -5.578942652  0.568091696 
# 
# 
# $c
# $c$coefficients
# (Intercept)           c 
# 0.163988    1.552544 
# 
# $c$residuals
# 1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
# 1.9319809 -1.8673426  0.2785686  3.3639259  0.9698881  0.9748069  1.6573032 
# 8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
# -1.9639900  4.4070009  0.3136801  1.7674514  2.6942398 -0.1145370 -0.9693461 
# 15         16         17         18         19         20 
# -1.4955686 -1.6776488 -1.9715968 -4.7164340 -4.1706428  0.5882611 
# 
# 
# $d
# $d$coefficients
# (Intercept)            d 
# -0.007487103  1.058906754 
# 
# $d$residuals
# 1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
# 2.8121452 -2.4525667  1.0110283  0.9249691 -0.2128186  0.4389798  0.2134230 
# 8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
# -0.6501655  2.9336712  0.7397345  3.5432953  1.7442696  1.8430766  1.2099507 
# 15         16         17         18         19         20 
# -0.6099311 -1.6920376 -1.5589256 -4.8965761 -7.7081168  2.3665949
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20*4), 20, 4)), letters[1:4])
d$h <- with(d, a + b + c + d + rnorm(20))
```